# using routes and passing a value from child widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I use routes to navigate between widgets and my problem as you see i have EditPhoto class and it requires id but i don't have the id in the main.dart. i want to give the id  from another widget are there anyway to do that ?

main.dart

```
routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomePage(),
          '/login': (context) => Login(),
          '/edit_photo':(context) => EditPhoto(),
        }
```

photo class

```
class EditPhoto {

final String id;

EditPhoto(this.id)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the documentation. 
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Step 1: Create a class to pass the arguments. In your case, it is just one `id`, but create a class, so that you may use it to pass some other parameters in future.

```
class EditPhotoArgs {
   final String id;
   EditPhotoArgs(this.id);
}
```

Step 2: On Button click, you can navigate to this screen, and pass the argument.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EditPhoto(),
        // Pass the arguments as part of the RouteSettings. The
        // ExtractArgumentScreen reads the arguments from these
        // settings.
        settings: RouteSettings(
          arguments: EditPhotoArgs('id'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Step 3: Get the ID from the Args in the EditPhoto screen

```
// inside EditPhoto
final EditPhotoArgs args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
print(args.id); // prints the ID passed from the previous screen
```